# From a text file consisting words and their emotions , i tried to print only the words for sad emotions using python. Someone please help me

Tags: python, nlp

```
import re
word ="sad"

sadwords=[]
with open('emotions.txt','r') as file :
    for line in file :
        if word in file:
            sadwords.append(word)

print(sadwords)
```

**From a text file consisting words and their emotions , i tried to print only the words for sad emotions using python. Someone please help me.**
[This is the emotion text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huh6p.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note in the example, `sadwords.append(word)` adds the word 'sad' to the list for each match and not the emotion.

Try:

```
word ="sad"

sadwords = []
with open('emotions.txt','r') as file :
    for line in file :
        if word in line:
            sadwords.append(line.split(':')[0])

print(sadwords)
```

If you want to strip out the quotes around the emotion then a regex can be used to extract just the emotion.

```python
import re
sadwords = []
with open('emotions.txt','r') as file :
    for line in file :
        m = re.search("'(.*?)': 'sad'", line)
        if m:
            sadwords.append(m.group(1))
print(sadwords)
```

**Output:**

```
['afflicted', 'agonized', 'anguished', ...]
```

Comment: Thanks @CodeMonkey. It worked. Also can you please tell why are we using array index "[0]".

Comment: [0] in first example if wanted to extract first part before the ":" but the regex in second example is the better approach.

Comment: The 2nd approach doesn't print anything. it just prints empty list "[]"

Comment: change match() to search(). The text input file might have leading space.

Answer (score 1):

Two tiny mistakes:

```
word = "sad"

sadwords=[]

with open('emotions.txt','r') as file :
    for line in file :
        # check if in line, not in file.
        if word in line:
            # append the line not the word.
            sadwords.append(line.split(":")[0].split("'")[1])
            #this gets the word and removes the ''.
```

Comment: Thanks @Micha. It worked. Also can you please tell why are we using array index "[0]".

Comment: because wen we call split on a string it returns a string array and we want the first element before the ":"

Comment: Thanks @Micha for helping out